# How to deploy ASP.NET Web API via xcopy

Tags: deployment, asp.net-web-api

All the content I have read regarding ASP.NET web api application deployment talks about using Web Deploy. However, I have not been able to get Web Deploy publishing to work.

So I have been looking how to manually deploy an ASP.NET Web API project using xcopy. However I have have been unable to find any instructions on how to do so. Has anyone deployed a Web API project using xcopy?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Publish wizard in Visual Studio with the 'Web Deploy Package' publish method selected (instead of 'Web Deploy')?

The result will be a zip file that you can XCOPY to the target server and then import using the IIS 'Import Application' wizard.

See here for step-by-step instructions:

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/import-a-package-through-iis-manager

If that doesn't suit, you can also use the 'File System' publish method to package the application for XCOPY deployment.

You can find the publish method on the 'Connection' tab of the VS Publish wizard.